# Google Colabでconda install コマンドを使ってmenpoをインストールしたいです。

Tags: anaconda, google-colaboratory

Google Colabで `conda install` コマンドを使ってmenpoをインストールしたいです。

[Beginner · The Menpo Project](https://www.menpo.org/installation/linux/beginner.html)
[誰でも簡単に量子計算自動化（google colabでpsi4） - Qiita](https://qiita.com/takashi-programming/items/71fcfb6ff12d383d7f78)

上記のサイトを参考に以下のコードを実行しましたが、4行目でエラーが起きmenpoが入りません。

どなたか解決策をご存じないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

**実行したコマンド:**

```
!wget -c https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!conda install -c conda-forge menpo menpofit menpodetect menpo3d
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::olefile-0.46-pyh9f0ad1d_1'.
FileNotFoundError(2, "No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/python3.7'")
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

FileNotFoundError(2, "No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/python3.7'")
```

Comment: @cubick ♦ 回答ありがとうございます。教えていただいたコマンドを実行したところ２行目でpython3.7: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directoryというエラーが出てしまいました。

Comment: menpoに限らず、ほかのパッケージも同様のエラーでインスト―ルできません。

Answer (score 1):

"Python 3.7 が見つからない" と出ているので、別途インストールする必要がありそうです。

実際に試したわけではありませんが、キーワードで検索してみるとSO英語版にて類似の質問と回答がありました。

**参考:**
[install python 3.7 via google colab as default python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63893246)

```py
# Install the python version
!apt-get install python3.7

# Select the version
!python3.7 setup.py
```